# Java CMS Being Ignored And Getting Full GC Instead

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm running a Java server that uses CMS for the tenured collector.  Running under a load-test, I see young collections about every 1s and tenured (concurrent) about every 5m.  This is good.

When I run with real traffic of about 1/2 capacity, I get young collections about every 4s and tenured (!parallel, stop the world!) about every 7m.  Why is the JVM deciding to do full stop-the-world collections instead of using the CMS collector?

From the gc.log you can see the "Full GC" being run and taking over 3s to complete.  There's no concurrent mode failure here.  Nothing is explicitly requesting a collection.

```
1350.596: [GC 1350.596: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 119275520 bytes, new threshold 3 (max 3)
- age   1:   34779376 bytes,   34779376 total
- age   2:   17072392 bytes,   51851768 total
- age   3:   24120992 bytes,   75972760 total
: 1765625K->116452K(1864192K), 0.1560370 secs] 3887120K->2277489K(5009920K), 0.1561920 secs] [Times: user=0.40 sys=0.04, real=0.16 secs] 
1355.106: [GC 1355.107: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 119275520 bytes, new threshold 3 (max 3)
- age   1:   44862680 bytes,   44862680 total
- age   2:   20363280 bytes,   65225960 total
- age   3:   16908840 bytes,   82134800 total
: 1747684K->123571K(1864192K), 0.1068880 secs] 3908721K->2307790K(5009920K), 0.1070130 secs] [Times: user=0.29 sys=0.04, real=0.11 secs] 
1356.106: [Full GC 1356.106: [CMS: 2184218K->1268401K(3145728K), 3.0678070 secs] 2682861K->1268401K(5009920K), [CMS Perm : 145090K->145060K(262144K)], 3.0679600 secs] [Times: user=3.05 sys=0.02, real=3.07 secs] 
1361.375: [GC 1361.375: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 119275520 bytes, new threshold 3 (max 3)
- age   1:   33708472 bytes,   33708472 total
: 1631232K->84465K(1864192K), 0.0189890 secs] 2899633K->1352866K(5009920K), 0.0191530 secs] [Times: user=0.19 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
1365.587: [GC 1365.587: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 119275520 bytes, new threshold 3 (max 3)
- age   1:   33475320 bytes,   33475320 total
- age   2:   22698536 bytes,   56173856 total
: 1715697K->67421K(1864192K), 0.0229540 secs] 2984098K->1335822K(5009920K), 0.0231240 secs] [Times: user=0.25 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
```

Here are the JVM flags:

```
-server -Xss256K -Xms5120M -Xmx5120M -XX:NewSize=2048M -XX:MaxNewSize=2048M
-XX:SurvivorRatio=7 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=1
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=73 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Xloggc:logs/gc.log
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=3
```

Comment: Something of interest...  After about 2800 seconds (+/- 200s) the CMS starts being used again.  There's typically 1 or 2 attempts that get aborted with "concurrent mode interrupted" and after that it's all successful CMS.  Traffic was unchanged during this time.

2415.457 - Full GC
... young collections ...
2684.320 - CMS-initial-mark (first CMS-mark anywhere in the log)
2684.436 - Full GC (concurrent mode interrupted)
... young ...
... another CMS interrupted ...
... young ...
3224.451 - CMS-initial-mark
3234.855 - young
3230.254 - CMS-remark
3231.972 - CMS-reset (done)
... all good ...

Comment: According to the [CMS code](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/6863023/diff-04-to-05/raw_files/new/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/concurrentMarkSweep/concurrentMarkSweepGeneration.cpp), the "concurrent mode interrupted" message occurs because of (a) `GCCause::is_user_requested_gc` or (b) `GCCause::is_serviceability_requested_gc`.  This means the cause is (a) `_java_lang_system_gc` or `_jvmti_force_gc`, or (b) `_jvmti_force_gc`, `_heap_inspection`, or `_heap_dump`.  It seems that the same thing could be the source of both the Full GC and the interruptions, but none of these should be happening.

Comment: Here's the first 8000 seconds of the [GC log file](http://www.backgroundexposure.com/gc.log.txt) from one server if you're interested.

Comment: Okay, get this...  If I reduce the threshold at which a Tenured GC starts, either by lowering the occupancy or the amount of heap ram then it uses the CMS collector right from the start.  Is there something in CMS that reverts to the Parallel collector if the interval between GCs is too long?

Comment: You might find it useful to add verbose:gc to your flags to get a bit more detail. The other thing I'd recommend for apparently obtuse GC errors is posting to the [hotspot-gc-use](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/hotspot-gc-use) list which is where you'll get a response from the jvm engineers.

Comment: also any jni in use btw? jni critical sections can delay/impact GC. Or some allocation behaviour (really large objects for example) at startup that cause it to do some slow path allocations?

Comment: I missed three flags in my cut/paste: -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps  I'll ask the devs about JNI but since changing the memory configuration can make this problem go away, I'm thinking it's something in the JVM itself.

Comment: Just discovered one more little tidbit...  These full collections come after about 5s of idleness in CPU tracking.  The task runs using between 3 & 4 cores, then drops to a flat line of 1 core for about 5s, then does the FullGC.

Comment: To follow up...  I never did discover the root cause of this but it eventually went away on its own with a newer version of the JVM.

Comment: In which version of the JVM did you see the problem and which version fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

If your survivor space is not large enough, it can trigger a Full GC. (It appears to be complaining about he survivor ratio)

Either you need to decrease your survivor ratio or a better solution is likely to be to increase your NewSize so that less objects survive from the eden space. I have an eden space of 6 GB ;)

Comment: Survivor space will hold generally around 4-6 cycles but since it's not diminishing the amount in each cycle I limit it to 3 cycles in order to reduce the amount of needless memcpy.

Comment: BTW, my Eden size is chosen to cause collections no more often than every 1s at full load and with an average stop-the-world time of 50ms.  Requests are typically answered in less than 50ms with 99.9% less than 250ms.

Comment: BTW: Creating a minimum of objects, the Eden space is enough for a whole day. I have one full GC every night at 5 am, no minor GCs at all. ;) The response time is less than 0.1 ms a high percentage of the time.

Comment: Interesting.  What's your request rate?  My target is 1000/sec (per server).

Comment: It equivalent to about 20/sec per server. It can handle a high percentage of requests without creating any objects.

Comment: That's great.  Unfortunately, the one I'm running creates a lot (though I'm working with the developers to cut that down).  Also, I "misspoke"...  It's 100/sec (per 4-core server -- not the most efficient Java binary I've run); 10 servers.

Comment: Soemthing I find useful when profiling the CPU is to turn on memory allocation monitoring as well.  This gives higher weight to object creation and can point to new areas to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall seeing a similar phenomenon last year when tuning a large heap to avoid full GC. I think you might want to decrease the size of eden. That's fairly large compared to the tenured generation.

What I believe might be happening is that more of your eden gets "old" at once with your 1/2 speed traffic than it does at full speed (where they're not surviving). Which means more of it needs to move to tenured at once. And if it doesn't fit at that time it might trigger a full GC to make room.

For reference here's what we use now for 6GB to 24GB heaps:

```
-XX:NewRatio=4 -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC  
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled  
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=68
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:logs/gc.log
```

It's fairly similar to yours already. The nice thing about using all ratios is that you can easily change the heap size and it (generally) scales appropriately. One other note is that `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` can typically use 40% less memory by reducing 64-bit addressing to 32-bit (only works up to 32GB).

Comment: A Full GC triggered because of a failure to promote Young objects to Tenured would appear in the log as a "concurrent mode failure" which is not present.  I've seen plenty of those in the past; the occupancy=80 is a result of careful tuning.  My requests are almost always answered in <250ms and so most of Eden is thrown out immediately with less than 10% getting copied to survivor.  About 1/4 to 1/2 of this gets thrown out in the next cycle after which it doesn't reduce much no matter how many more copies are allowed (hence the TenuringThreshold=3).  Less than 5% of Eden space gets tenured.

Comment: Apparently I spoke too soon.  Lowering my "occupancy fraction" to 60 did indeed stop this.  Perhaps it's not considered a "concurrent mode failure" unless the JVM has attempted at least one CMS collection since start-up (though why it didn't, I don't understand).  Even the counters internal to the JVM didn't count it as such, log messages or no.

Now...  Why would moving 15-30MB to a fresh Tenured space of 3G have a problem with an occupancy of 70 but work with 65?  30MB is only 1% of 3G.